# Get Excel file from HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-core

I am working on a ASP.NET Core 2.2 project and I need to download my Excel with my browser, but when I am doing my request, I just get some Json.

My Excel is in the stream, and the stream is not empty !

Here is my code :

```
HttpResponseMessage message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);

            streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Excel.xlsx";

            message.Content = streamContent;

            return message;
```

And here is the response I get :

```
{"version":{"major":1,"minor":1,"build":-1,"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1},"content":{"headers":[{"key":"Content-Type","value":["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"]},{"key":"Content-Disposition","value":["attachment; filename=Excel.xlsx"]}]},"statusCode":200,"reasonPhrase":"OK","headers":[],"requestMessage":null,"isSuccessStatusCode":true}
```

So, do someone know how I can send my Excel file with HttpResponseMessage ?

I can download my excel file using Filesteam, but I don't want to use that way because I can't get any Http error message (Bad request, Internal, etc.)
But if someone know how I can send message like this and returning a Filestream, I will be glad to read your advice !

EDIT : Here is the code when I am returning a FileStreamResult

```
                return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

Comment: Where is that excel file located?

Comment: My file is on a stream created by my project !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could read as Byte array from Stream, and return FileContentResult.

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace DemoWebCore.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class FilesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/files/sample.png
        [HttpGet("{fileName}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Get(string fileName)
        {
            var cd = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline")
            {
                FileName = "Excel.xlsx"
            };
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
            StreamContent stream = YOUR_STREAM_SOURCE
            byte[] content = await stream.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            return File(content, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your help, I just had to return a ActionResult like your example instead of a FileStreamResult, now everything is Ok !